# Why aren't there any Stack Exchange dry-erase markers?

Tags: discussion, swag

I was at Stack Exchange HQ earlier for the [Reinvent 311](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/what-is-reinvent-311-hint-its-an-nyc-hackathon) hackathon, and I got to meet some pretty cool people and got some neat swag. I noticed that while there were pens and permanent markers with the Stack Exchange insignia, there weren't any dry-erase markers! I thought it was odd, because, after all, programmers use dry-erase markers at least as often as pens.

I think it would be a cool thing for you to have, even to help the Stack Exchange developers who lose their own markers in their offices.

This is just a suggestion, but I'm posting it here because I told [Jarrod](https://stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) that I would. Thanks for a great event and a fun night.

Comment: Well I'm glad I checked what turned out to be my retractable Stack Exchange sharpie.  That could have easily pissed off a whiteboard owner...

Comment: for Stack Exchange, it would be wrong to call these markers "dry-erase". Correct name should be "[meta-tag:edit]-[meta-tag:delete]"

Comment: I believe we actually _have_ these, just none in the office. Going to send them all to me and say we don't have any after all, err, I mean, check.

Comment: Tim, dija find any?